# Git post-update and conflicts

Tags: git, conflict, git-bare

I currently have a following Git workflow **local normal git repo** -> **remote bare git repo** -> **staging normal git repo**. My *bare* repository has a post-update hook, which 
looks like this:

```
cd /path/to/my/staging/repo
unset GIT_DIR
git pull bare master
```

Everything seem to work fine, except for one thing: **every time I change a file, and execute "git push origin master", the modified bits a treated as conflicts** (on Heroku the new changes just overrides the old ones, not sure exactly what happens but it seems so). How to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it seems that I have found a solution, adding these two lines:

```
git fetch bare
git reset --hard bare/master
```

instead of `git pull bare master`, gave the needed result.